# Groovy Batch Update with Clob

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to run a batch update using a clob, but my table is getting updated with the clobs memory address instead of the clob value.

```
def updateCounts = sql
    .withBatch('UPDATE my_table SET clob_column = ? WHERE id = ?') { stmt ->
        fileList.each { fileName->

            Clob commentClob = CLOB.createTemporary(sql.getConnection(), false, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION)
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
                new FileReader(theInfoFile), 
                CSVParser.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, 
                CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, 1)
            String[] row;

            while ((row = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                commentClob.truncate(0)
                commentClob.setString(1,"${row[17]}")
                stmt.addBatch([commentClob,row[0]])
            }
        }
}
```

The value that I'm seeing in the database is "oracle.sql.CLOB@15500a8". Any suggestions on how to handle the clob value?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you could try the oracle specific `characterOutputStream`:

```
commentClob.characterOutputStream << row[17]
```

it's possible you would need to type the variable as:

```
OracleClob commentClob = ...
```

instead of:

```
Clob commentClob = ...
```

but groovy being groovy, you probably would not need to.